# Increment a value continuously and if the date is changed set the variable to zero

Tags: python

```
from datetime import datetime, date
import time
x = 0
def main():
    global x
    while(1):
        x = x+1
        print(x)
        today_date = date.today()
        print(today_date)
        time.sleep(10)

main()
```

but if there is a changes in date the value of x should become zero and again need to start incrementing. then my output should be as follows

```
1
2020-05-06
2
2020-05-06
.
.
1
2020 -05-07
2
2020-05-07
.
.
.
```

Can someone help me.

Answer (score 1):

```
from datetime import datetime, date
import time
x = 0
last_date = date.today()
def main():
    global x
    while(1):
        x = x+1
        print(x)
        today_date = date.today()
        if last_date != today_date:
            x = 0
            last_date = today_date   
        print(today_date)
        time.sleep(10)

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import time
from datetime import date
def Cnt():
     cur = date.today()
     old = None
     x = 0
     while True:
         old, cur = cur, date.today()
         if cur != old:
             x = 1
         else:
             x += 1
         yield str(cur), str(x)

 cnt = Cnt()
 while True:
     print('\n'.join(next(cnt))
     time.sleep(10)
```